# Creating Issue Labels with Terraform using the Github Provider

Tags: github, terraform, terraform-provider-github

I'm trying to automate my repository setup with terraform. First thing is creating issue labels for a bunch of repos using the Terraform Guthub provider.

It works when I explicitly state the repo and the labels:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

# Use env-var
provider "github" {}

data "github_repository" "trashbox" {
  full_name = "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/trashbox"
}

resource "github_issue_label" "bug" {
  repository  = data.github_repository.trashbox.id
  name        = "bug"
  description = "Something is not working"
  color       = "B60205"
}

resource "github_issue_label" "security" {
  repository  = data.github_repository.trashbox.id
  name        = "security"
  description = "CVEs, code scan violations, etc."
  color       = "cd3ad7"
}
```

But this would mean that I would have to duplicate everything for another repo. Or at least that I need to update my terraform config manually when I add another repo. I'd prever to have all relevant repos auto-detected.

Auto-detecting works with this snippet ... this returns all repos I want to configure.

```
data "github_repositories" "repos" {
  query           = "user:sebastian-sommerfeld-io archived:false"
  include_repo_id = true
}
```

But now I cannot create the labels. When I run `terraform apply` I always get this error:

```
Error: POST https://api.github.com/repos/sebastian-sommerfeld-io/sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-sommerfeld-io/labels: 404 Not Found []

  with github_issue_label.bug["sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-sommerfeld-io"],
  on issues.tf line 1, in resource "github_issue_label" "bug":
   1: resource "github_issue_label" "bug" {
```

The odd thing is, that `terraform plan` does not hint at any error:

```
# github_issue_label.bug["sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-sommerfeld-io"] will be created
+ resource "github_issue_label" "bug" {
    + color       = "B60205"
    + description = "Something is not working"
    + etag        = (known after apply)
    + id          = (known after apply)
    + name        = "bug"
    + repository  = "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-sommerfeld-io"
    + url         = (known after apply)
  }
```

My complete Terraform config which generates the outputs from `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` is this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

# Use env-var
provider "github" {}

data "github_repositories" "repos" {
  query           = "user:sebastian-sommerfeld-io archived:false"
  include_repo_id = true
}

resource "github_issue_label" "bug" {
  for_each    = toset(data.github_repositories.repos.full_names)
  repository  = each.value
  name        = "bug"
  description = "Something is not working"
  color       = "B60205"
}
```

The repositories are queried correctly. I confirmed this via:

```
output "affected_repos" {
  value       = data.github_repositories.repos.full_names
  description = "Github Repos"
}
```

This lists all repos correctly:

```
affected_repos = tolist([
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-sommerfeld-io",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/jarvis",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/github-action-generate-docs",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/configs",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-tafelboy-de",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-numero-uno-de",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-masterblender-de",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/monitoring",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/github-action-update-antora-yml",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/github-action-generate-readme",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/docker-image-tf-graph-beautifier",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/docker-image-jq",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/docker-image-git",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/docker-image-ftp-client",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/docker-image-folderslint",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/docker-image-adoc-antora",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/trashbox",
  "sebastian-sommerfeld-io/provinzial",
])
```

I guess I don't get the for_each stuff right. Can anyone help me? I want to query all my repos taht fit my criteria and add labels to them.

---

UPDATE: I just detected that with my static approach I pass `id`, not `full_name`. I updated my code to this (snippet from above):

```
resource "github_issue_label" "bug" {
  for_each    = data.github_repositories.repos.repo_ids
  repository  = each.value
  name        = "bug"
  description = "Something is not working"
  color       = "B60205"
}
```

Now at least the error message is different:

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on issues.tf line 2, in resource "github_issue_label" "bug":
│    2:   for_each    = data.github_repositories.repos.repo_ids
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.github_repositories.repos.repo_ids is list of number with 18 elements
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
│ must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type
│ list of number.
```

Comment: Does the plan output show all the repos or only one? If `for_each` works it should show all of them. In other words, does the output show anything else than `github_issue_label.bug["sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-sommerfeld-io"]`?

Comment: The output block from `terraform plan` is just an excerpt. It actually prints this block about 20 times (one time per repo). So yes I do see multiple repos there and no error message at all.

Comment: I guess a got a little closer by updating the for_each (see the update in my question). I updated this to `for_each    = toset(data.github_repositories.repos.repo_ids)` so I cast this to a set. Not I get the error `The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type number.` ... So this is just a matter of casting to a set of strings now? But maybe this is not the elegant way? Or the way the Github Provider is supposed to be used?

Comment: It seems there is a GH issue already [open](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/1238) for what you are experiencing.

Comment: Damn it! This looks similar to my issue ... Can you think of another way of adding my labels without duplicating code for every repo and label?

Comment: Not really, maybe try with `count`? Something like `count = length(data.github_repositories.repos.full_names)` and then `repository  = data.github_repositories.repos[count.index].full_names`.

Comment: I decided to not generate everything dynamically based on github data. So I have to define every repo by name. But it occured to me that the repos won't be 100% equal anyway. Labels seemed like an easy entry into this so I started with it. But I always planned to populate the repos with Github Actions Secrets. And they will differ from repo to repo anyway. So I had to define them anyway. Maybe I can include / reuse the labels settings somehow so I don't repeat myself ...Many thanks for your help and opinion and your very quick responses.